# Can A PictureBox Load Different Images As A Variable Changes?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to change the image in a picture box in Visual Studios Windows Form Application according to a variable?

I've tried the code below where "yellow_back" is the name of the image in the folder.

```
string colour = "yellow_back";
this.PlayerHand2.Image = global::CardsWFA.Properties.Resources.colour;
```

I received the error:
Error   CS0117  'Resources' does not contain a definition for 'colour'
Is there a way to do this, or do I need to find an alternative?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Raise an event when the property changes and load the image again in the event handler.

Comment: Do you have an Image in `Properties.Resources` which you called `colour`? i.e., when you press the *dot* after `Properties.Resources`, does Intellisense show you that name?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Its trying to get the image resource with the name of your variable 'colour'

try to set the variable with your resource image and then set the picturebox image property with that variable. (as the code bellow).

Ex:

```
        var colour = global::CardsWFA.Properties.Resources.yellow_back;
        this.PlayerHand2.Image = color;
        this.PlayerHand2.Refresh();
```

PS:
Do you have an image called colour? or an image called "yellow_back"?

Comment: Apparently, the error is that the Resource object is not found. Calling `Refresh()` is not required.

Comment: *I received the error: Error CS0117 'Resources' does not contain a definition for 'colour'*.

Comment: My variable? `Properties.Resources.colour` is the name of an object loaded in the Projects's Resources. An object with that name is there or is not. If it's there and it references an Image, you can assign it to a control's Image property. The error says it's not there or it doesn't have that name, so the ResourceManager can't find it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196165/discussion-between-gabriel-goncalves-and-jimi).

Comment: The image is called yellow_back, colour is the variable storing yellow_back.